# compute a column based on other columns pandas

Tags: python, pandas

Here is a dataset, I wanna find out which user view which item less than 10s(deep_view - view <10). The dataset is like this:

```
                               user_id  item_id  action_type  action_time
0   0365F7AE-5048-42B3-BB2C-8E637A380A3E   557082        view   1487423564
1   0365F7AE-5048-42B3-BB2C-8E637A380A3E   557166        view   1487424075 
2   0365F7AE-5048-42B3-BB2C-8E637A380A3E   555824        view   1487424241
5   0365F7AE-5048-42B3-BB2C-8E637A380A3E   555824   deep_view   1487424345 
3   0365F7AE-5048-42B3-BB2C-8E637A380A3E   554390        view   1487424395
4   0365F7AE-5048-42B3-BB2C-8E637A380A3E   557166   deep_view   1487424175    
6   0365F7AE-5048-42B3-BB2C-8E637A380A3E   557082   deep_view   1487423680
7   0365F7AE-5048-42B3-BB2C-8E637A380A3E   554390   deep_view   1487424422 
8   06068254-792D-4AFE-AC6C-DE43DB15D735   556134        view   1487417354
9   06068254-792D-4AFE-AC6C-DE43DB15D735   556134   deep_view   1487417411  
10  06068254-792D-4AFE-AC6C-DE43DB15D735   550176        view   1487400366  
11  077F63F3-3DF4-4041-B3C9-7BAB2BDCA795   519444        view   1487415176  
12  077F63F3-3DF4-4041-B3C9-7BAB2BDCA795   555729   deep_view   1487412841  
13  077F63F3-3DF4-4041-B3C9-7BAB2BDCA795   555171   deep_view   1487414707 
14  077F63F3-3DF4-4041-B3C9-7BAB2BDCA795   555744        view   1487412883 
15  077F63F3-3DF4-4041-B3C9-7BAB2BDCA795   555757        view   1487412616 
16  077F63F3-3DF4-4041-B3C9-7BAB2BDCA795   555337        view   1487414331  
17  077F63F3-3DF4-4041-B3C9-7BAB2BDCA795   555784        view   1487413081  
18  077F63F3-3DF4-4041-B3C9-7BAB2BDCA795   555653        view   1487412036
19  077F63F3-3DF4-4041-B3C9-7BAB2BDCA795   555537        view   1487413842
```

And I've tried this code:

```
def short_time(data):
    data = data.sort_values(by=['user_id', 'action_time'])
    id = []
    for i in range(data.shape[0] - 1):
        if data['action_type'][data.index[i]] == 'view' and data['action_type'][data.index[i + 1]] == 'deep_view' and \
                        data['user_id'][data.index[i]] == data['user_id'][data.index[i + 1]] \
                and data['item_id'][data.index[i]] == data['item_id'][data.index[i + 1]]:
            if data['action_time'][data.index[i + 1]] - data["action_time"][data.index[i]] < 10:
                id.append(data.index[i])
    return data.loc[id, :]
```

It works , but it takes so many loops. Any better solutions ?Here's the part of the outputs:

```
          user_id  item_id  action_type  action_time
301800     135973   558284        view   1487386449
457083     149124   544766        view   1487349898
203814    1258134   538039        view   1487382777
454537    1489322   550339        view   1487419315
131863   11703060   553010        view   1487424398
132345   11705467   546168        view   1487369955
137092   11761967   471721        view   1487425655
137236   11765536   539269        view   1487370412
137229   11765536   542229        view   1487370465
137238   11765536   462871        view   1487370491
137241   11765536   542217        view   1487370845
137276   11765536   550339        view   1487379656
137263   11765536   539302        view   1487379832
137275   11765536   541951        view   1487380143
137278   11765536   550737        view   1487381556
137208   11765536   541946        view   1487412335
138095   11776713   552341        view   1487413089
138898   11783870   542197        view   1487406728
138904   11783870   542235        view   1487406763
138903   11783870   541683        view   1487407348
138905   11783870   496537        view   1487407465
139175   11785631   550982        view   1487384606
```

What's more ,after finishing this task, I want to find out whoever have read the item in the first part *(item = data.loc[id, :]['item_id']*), I tried *data[data['item_id']==item]* it failed. I don't want to use for...in item...

for example:

As you can see, 558284 is a item_id that in the first task output.So I wanna find out whoever had read this item in the dataset. And in the dataset we can find this

```
                                user_id  item_id  action_type  action_time
2   0365F7AE-5048-42B3-BB2C-8E637A380A3E   555824        view   1487424241
5   0365F7AE-5048-42B3-BB2C-8E637A380A3E   555824   deep_view   1487424345
```

So the target is find out all the rows that contains the item_id in the first task output.
anyone helps?
Thanks.

Comment: Could you provide an example of the final output?

Comment: @mischi I've added the example to it...thank you...

Comment: @Lgiro  I think this is different from that...this contains the compute between rows...

Comment: Why do the user ID formats change between the first set of data and the point where you say "Here's part of the outputs:"?

Comment: sorry, the first set of data is only a part of the whole dataset...@pshep123